# Magento attributes with different sorting

Tags: magento, sorting, attributes

I am new to php, What i want is if i can define sorting order to ascending to only products that are showing by price by doing something like this in the file

Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListSort

```
$options[] = array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
    'value' => 'price'
    'getCurrentDirection' => 'asc'
);
```

and rest of the attributes with descending order.

Unfortunately, doesn't seem to be working.
Can anyone help?

Comment: I do not get your question. Please try to describe the problem and your idea more clearly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking in the wrong file. The ListSort file you describe above merely lists the available options for sort by. It does nothing to the current sort.

Also, the file you referenced to is in the Adminhtml scope. If you need to change the default sort on the frontend, you should look elsewhere.

Your question, if I understand correctly, is how to sort ASC by default if price is selected for sort by, while sorting DESC by default is another attribute is used for sort by.

For the frontend, you should take a look at the getCurrentOrder() function in the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar file. Here you have both the default direction and the sort order available. It is not good practice to hack app/core/Mage files, but you could copy this file and place it in app/local/Mage/* (exact same dir as the core file) and it will automatically overload the default method.

For the backend, you could look at the _prepareCollection() function in the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget file. The default sort is 'desc', so all you need to do is change it to 'asc' for price. Here too, you should make a copy in app/local/Mage/*. You could try something like this (For Magento 1.7.1.0, this is line 507-508):

change

```
$columnId = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameSort(), $this->_defaultSort);
$dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir);
```

to

```
$columnId = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameSort(), $this->_defaultSort);
if($this->getVarNameSort() == 'price') {
    $dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), 'asc');
} else {
    $dir      = $this->getParam($this->getVarNameDir(), $this->_defaultDir);
}
```

I hope this helps!